# PHP - Convert String Timezone Format to Offset Integer

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

Pretty straightforward:

PHP returns timezones in the following format:

```
"America/Los_Angeles"
```

I want to convert it to:

```
-7
```

I found many codes to convert it, calculating differences with custom functions.. but as a minimalist I can't believe there isn't a simpler way (perhaps a datetime function) to get the value right away.. anyone know about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$dateTimeZone = new DateTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
$date = new DateTime('', $dateTimeZone);
echo $dateTimeZone->getOffset($date)/60/60;
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/174673)

Comment: `new DateTime(null, $dateTimeZone)` + PHP8.2: deprecated passing null to parameter #1 ($datetime) of type string. Pass an empty string `''` instead.

Answer (score 3):

PHP uses the standard time zones from [the IANA time zone database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

"America/Los_Angeles" is *not* the same as -7.  -7 is a "time zone offset", not a "time zone".  Read "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Consider that `"America/Los_Angeles"` represents US Pacific Time, which is only -7 during Pacific Daylight Time (PDT).  The rest of the year, it is in Pacific Standard Time (PST), which is -8.

The code provided in John's answer will correctly give you the offset that a time zone uses for the *current* date and time.  Recognize that the value will change depending on when you run the code.

Also, you should realize that while you can determine the offset for a particular time zone at any particular moment, the reverse is not true.  You *cannot* treat -7 as a time zone and expect someone to be able to tell that it is Pacific Daylight Time.  Consider that -7 also applies to Mountain Standard Time, which Arizona uses year-round.